# JavaScript Array to Object: changing array elements to Object property and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to build a function that can take in an array, and without changing the array, return an object whose property is the first element of that array, and that property's value is the last element of the array:

example:

```
var array = ["Orange", "glass", "hat", "juicy", "green"]

function firstAndLast(array){
}

//output should be:

{
    Orange : 'green'
}
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: When you tried to make the function yourself, where did you get stuck? Which part do you not know how to do?

Comment: What if the array is empty or has only one element? Or if the first element isn't a string?

Comment: JJJ, my code was:
function firstAndLast(array){
     var object = { array[0] : array[array.length-1]};
     console.log(object)
}
I even unsuccessfully went with for loops when that didn't work. I'm pretty disappointed with myself that it was just a matter of missed brackets. I should have reviewed literal notation.  Thank you for the follow up question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
var arr= ["Orange", "glass", "hat", "juicy", "green"]


function firstAndLast(arr){
    return {[arr[0]] : arr[arr.length - 1]}
}
```

result

```
{ Orange : 'green' }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple actually

```js
var array = ["Orange", "glass", "hat", "juicy", "green"];

// take the first elem and map it to the last element
// the index of the last element being array.length - 1
var res = {[array[0]] : array[array.length - 1]};

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var array = ["Orange", "glass", "hat", "juicy", "green"];
 
 var myelem = {[array[0]] : array[array.length-1]};
 
 console.log(myelem);
```